# I have two given names and one surname. Is it a problem if I omit the surname from my ticket?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airports

I have two names as my given name in the passport and I typically just use this as my first and last name. However, my passport has a surname too which I almost never use. Due to this, I mistakenly provided my given name as first and last name.

As per the passport, 
Surname : AAAA
Given name(s) : BBBB CCCC

In the ticket,
First name : BBBB
Last name : CCCC

The credit card I've used to make this booking has my name as BBBB CCCC.

Will this create a problem at the travel time?

Update : the airline says that they can't update the name in the ticket. They are saying that since they have made a remark of the passport details boarding will not be a problem but I might face problems at immigration. Do they check name details in itenerary to exactly match passport at the time of immigration? Is that true in your experience?

Update : Travelled without any problem, neither at boarding gate, immigration nor after arrival at border police control.

Comment: Yes it certainly might. While it is not true that the names must exactly match, for the surname on the ticket to be completely different to the surname on the passport can cause you difficulties. Where is it that you are going?

Comment: Travelling from Mumbai to Rome via Istanbul. Booked in Turkish Airlines. Turkish airlines refuses to update the name and also refusing to provide any refund. I just have an option to either forfeit the ticket or take my chances.

Comment: @Calchas: Can you please elaborate at what stages can this create problems? Since, yours and Boris's answers are conflicting, I can't really make up my mind about this. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should not be an issue, but maybe you should bring some other form of identification along with you, such as a driver license (or indeed a few credit cards, checkbook, etc..), but something with your photo on it is best I guess.

Or just contact the airline, I'm sure you're not the first one.

Comment: Thanks. Contacted the airline. They said they have made a remark of the correct name but will not issue a ticket with updated information not even for a fee. Also told me that you will face a problem at border control. They are asking me to forfeit the booking and rebook or travel at my own risk.

Comment: You won't have an issue at the border : all that matters is that your photo corresponds to your face, sometimes they don't even need your flight ticket. Regarding the name on the ticket, if I understand correctly, BBBB and CCCC are both on your passport and your ticket right? So having AAAA in addition on your passport should not be an issue.

Comment: That's very helpful. Given Name(s) on passport is BBBB CCCC, Surname on passport is AAAA. In ticket passenger name is : BBBB CCCC. No spelling errors. I also have additional photo IDs and credit cards with name listed as BBBB CCCC. Someone mentioned that TSA secure flight list is compiled based on the surname and that is where this will be an issue, is that true? Or is it only true for travel within the United States? I am flying on Turkish Airlines from Mumbai to Rome with a 2 hours layover and flight change in Istanbul.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you will have any problems. After all, if the airline cannot refund your ticket... travel and you will see what happens ! :)