# How to buy a plane ticket if I have two last names?

Tags: tickets, airlines, cathay-pacific

I am trying to book a plane ticket with [Cathay Pacific Airlines](https://www.cathaypacific.com/cx/fr_FR.html). I am Spanish so I have one name and two last names.
When I try to introduce the information in the webpage of the airline I can't use spaces in the "Surname" field so I can either put just the first one of them or both of them without any separation.

What should I do? I'm leaning towards the second option but I don't know if I would have any problems. I have also contacted the airline because I couldn't find any information in their web.

Comment: Another option would be to use a hyphen. [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) strikes again.

Comment: I have two first names and many times in online reservation systems I've seen (at least in Brazil) "if you have two names, put them together without a hyphen or space". So for John James Smith I'm putting first name field as "JOHNJAMES" and I never had issues (at least so far ;) )

Comment: Related, almost the same: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67600/international-flight-ticket-booked-without-providing-the-surname-as-per-the-pass

Comment: If you were adventurous you could try inserting a Unicode no-break space  :-)

Answer (score 3):

I just got a reply from the airline saying exactly:

> In that case it is preferable to write both your last names without any separations between them.